Why does React (and/or Next) remove the transform property when navigating around my app?
I have a simple React component (some randomly placed "stars") that does not want to keep inline styling when navigating around my app - specifically the transform property is removed (see screenshots below). Reloading the page will add the transform params I feed it but will delete it, again, when navigating.
const stars = [
  {
    s: 1.01008930445147,
    curR: 1012.8646405396803,
    yRotate: 82.08700538334165,
    xRotate: -34.590599732775004,
    bgColor: 'yellow',
  },
  {
    s: 0.6837385344214948,
    curR: 968.297526216683,
    yRotate: 17.954768821347578,
    xRotate: -45.47975056098913,
    bgColor: 'blue',
  },
  {
    s: 0.8286765657990229,
    curR: 1598.3185292691123,
    yRotate: 196.0609316224604,
    xRotate: -9.90854666326314,
    bgColor: 'green',
  },
];

function Stars() {
  return (
    <>
      {stars.map((star) => {
        return (
          <div
            className="star"
            style={{
              transform:
                ' translate3d(0,0,-' +
                star.curR +
                'px) rotateY(' +
                star.yRotate +
                'deg) rotateX(' +
                star.xRotate +
                'deg) scale(' +
                star.s +
                ');',
              transformOrigin: '0 0 ' + star.curR + 'px',
              backgroundColor: star.bgColor,
            }}
          ></div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}

export default function SomeParentComponent() {
  return (
    <div className="stars">
      <Stars />
    </div>
  );
}

.stars {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: perspective(500px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: absolute;
    perspective-origin: 50% 100%;

    .star {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform-origin: 0 0 -300px;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, -300px) translate(-50% -50%);
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      background-color: $off-white;
      height: 3px;
      width: 3px;
      border-radius: 99px;
      z-index: 5;
    }
  }

Screenshot of code on initial load
Screenshot of code after navigating within app
I added bgColor after the transform for testing, thinking react was removing anything after the transform-origin property but, no, it only removes transform styling.
I haven't really delved into workarounds - I think I can force it to re-render, but want to understand why transform doesn't work.
Some notes:

The original stars object contains 700 items; I thought referencing such a large object was the culprit but I shortened it to three items and it's still not working.

I'm using Next.js and the Pages Router


